# Does youtube api need a pfx certificate?

Tags: youtube-api, windows-store-apps

I tried to run this Windows 8 app [sample code](https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=82d44ba9ac345665&id=82D44BA9AC345665%21400) for youtube 
linked from [this article](http://www.mzekiosmancik.com/2012/11/30/windows-8-store-apps-_-youtube-video-on-media-element/)

but it doesn't work because of youtube_TemporaryKey.pfx which is not correct: what I should do to get the correct one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't face any problem of `youtube_TemporaryKey.pfx`, working fine for me. Though you can create test certificate of you own.

1. Open Package.appxmanifest file.
2. Go to "Packaging" tab.
3. Click on "Choose Certificate" button.
4. You will see a combo box, select "Create test certificate".
5. Fill the form and new .PFX file will be added to project.

Comment: ok thank you but I still don't understand : what's the purpose of this pfx certificate ? Is it part of Google Youtube Requirements ?

Comment: No, it's required in all the Windows Store App. It's a security certificate.